# How exactly do viruses get on computer when watching online porn?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus

I've been hearing that your computer could get infected when you visit porn sites, especially when watching videos.

But how exactly do viruses get on client side? Is it by cache? Or maybe by exploiting flash player/browser vulnerabilities? Could you give an example? How likely is to get infected such way?

*Later Edit:* @Polynomial gives a pretty good list of attack vectors [here.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17852/is-there-a-real-possibility-of-getting-malware-by-drive-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common vectors:

- Drive by download - Download is forced on to your computer, and you may either be forced or tempted to execute a malicious file. You are just browsing and all of a sudden you get freebooks.pdf.dll, or worse a browser/OS flaw lets the download happen without you seeing it.
- Malicious advertisement with malicious javascript - Malicious javascript takes advantage of a browser flaw to exploit your system.

This isn't limited to porn. There are lots of other sorts of sites that have these problems.